# How to restart the disabled Scheduled tasks using CLI/PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have deployed Scheduled tasks through the Azure DevOps pipelines. Before deploying the Scheduled tasks, I am first stopping all the Scheduled tasks, and after deployment, I will enable all the Scheduled tasks. After enabling all the Scheduled tasks, a few of the scheduled services were disabled automatically.

```
$taskService = Get-Process test.ScheduledTasks.Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($taskService) {
    Stop-Process -name test.ScheduledTasks.Service -Force
}

schtasks.exe /CHANGE /TN "testtask" /DISABLE

#Enable Tasks

schtasks.exe /CHANGE /TN "testtask" /ENABLE
```

How to restart the disabled Scheduled tasks using CLI/PowerShell script?

Comment: There are powershell commands to start/stop/enable/disable scheduled tasks, like `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TestTask' | Disable-ScheduledTask`. "Scheduled tasks" are not the same thing as "Windows Services" - can you clarify what you are trying to do?